# Exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $P(X>\epsilon)>0$

Tags: probability-theory

I have the next exercice:

Let $(X_n)_n$ a sequence of random variables i.i.d with law $X$, where $X\ge 0$ almost surely et $P(X>0)>0$.

1. Show that exists $\epsilon \ge 0$ such that $P(X>\epsilon)>0$.
2. Let $A_n=\{X_n\ge \epsilon\}$. What can be said about the set $\limsup A_n$?

My ideas:

1. Let $B_k=\{X\ge\frac{1}{k}\}$

   $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k=\{X>0\}$

   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(B_k)\ge P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k)=P(X>0)>0$, i.e exist $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P(X\ge\frac{1}{m})=P(B_m)>0$.

Where $\epsilon =\frac{1}{m}$.

My idea is correct? and they could give me suggestions for the second item.

Comment: The $B_k$ are not disjoint so the equality between the sum of probabilities and the probability of the union does not hold. Replace it with an inequality, and your reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For the second question apply the Borel cantelli lemma, i.e. compute $\sum P(A_n)$. Is it finite or infinite? What does it tell you about $P(\limsup A_n)$?

Your proof for one does not work. It is not true that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(B_k)=P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k)$. It is true by measure continuity that $\sup P(B_k)=\lim P(B_k)=P(X>0)>0$. Hence there exists at least one $k$ such that $P(B_k)>0$.

Comment: I found that $\sum P(A_n)$ is finite and by Borel Cantelli Lemma $P(\limsup A_n) =0$

Comment: By the proof of a) we know that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $P(X\geq \epsilon)>0$. In particular $P(A_n)=P(X_n\geq \epsilon)=P(X\geq \epsilon)>0$, so the sum diverges (as $\sum P(A_n)=\sum P(X\geq \epsilon)=\infty$) By Borel cantelli, $P(\limsup A_n)=1$ since the $X_i$ are independent.